# Angular ul list self remove or update data and refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am using angular 7 and I have some data displayed using `<ul> <li>` ....

In each LI I have a close button and a click event which runs some code that will remove the item from the data.

Here's the code for the component html:

```
<ul *ngFor="let dat of data">
  <li>
    <span>{{dat.name}}</span>
    <span (click)="removeFromData(dat.name)">
      <span>X</span>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The data looks like this in the ts file:

```
data: [
    { name: 'name 1' },
    { name: 'another name' }
];
```

I need to either be able to re-run / the data so I get an updated view or a way of just making the item disappear.

How can I do this?

Comment: in place of data if you should observable, like `Subject` then it is possible.

Comment: can you provide `ts` file

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: please check the answer I gave. let me know if it is working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**component.ts-**

```
data = [
        {name:'ashish'},
        {name:'nakul'},
        {name:'vikas'},
        {name:'abhi'},
        {name:'syam'}
      ];

removeFromData(name:string){
    this.data = this.data.filter(val=>val.name!==name);
  }
```

**component.html-**

```
<ul *ngFor="let dat of data">
  <li>
    <span>{{dat.name}}</span>
    <button (click)="removeFromData(dat.name)">
      <span>X</span>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

for more info check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ucuzy5)